# I'm not sure that my ajax navigation works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, history

I tried to make menu with history api. But it seems to me it works not fine, and I got reasons to think so:

1 my "title" not changing

2 if I click to fast on my links I got a blink of a page as it is reloaded but it shouldn't!(but if I click slow it is ok. How to prevent reload or blinking?)

please tell me waht I do wrong

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

 sliderStartUp()




//menu click
 $('.navigation').click(function(){

//fill the storage
var storage = {
 url: $(this).children('a').attr('href'),
 title: $(this).children('a').attr('title')
 };

 history.pushState(null, storage.title, storage.url );



    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).children('a').prop("href"),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){ //if the data you return is a css notation      (eg: #id) of the location of the title name
   JqObj = $(data);
   var addSmth = JqObj.find('#central').html();
  $("#central").html('').html(addSmth);
sliderStartUp()

  }
   });
 return false;

  });

function sliderStartUp(){
  $('#slider').nivoSlider({
effect: 'fold',
animSpeed: '500',
pauseTime: '4000'
});

 }




 });
```

here is my havigarion

```
 <ul id="navig">
 <?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/") 
{
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/index";
}
$arrayNav = array(  array (
                        'name' => 'yyyyyy',
                        'title' => 'yyyyyyyyyyy',
                        'link' =>'http://bistro.loc/index',
                        'identificator' => 'id_index',
                        'pattern' => '/index/i'
                            ),
                    array (
                        'name' => 'xxxxxx',
                        'title' => 'xxxxxxx',
                        'link' => http://bistro.loc/price',
                        'identificator' => 'id_price',
                        'pattern' => '/price/i'
                            ),
                    array (
                        'name' => 'aaa',
                        'title' => '',
                        'link' => 'http://bistro.loc/#' ,   
                        'identificator' => 'id_serv',
                        'pattern' => '/#/i'
                            ),
                    array (
                        'name' => 'ssss',
                        'title' => '',
                        'link' => 'http://bistro.loc/#' ,   
                        'identificator' => 'id_cont',
                        'pattern' => '/#/i'
                            ),
                    array (
                        'name' => 'dddd',
                        'title' => '',
                        'link' => 'http://bistro.loc/#' ,   
                        'identificator' => 'id_about',                          
                        'pattern' => '/#/i'                     
                            ));
 foreach ($arrayNav as $item)
{if (preg_match($item['pattern'],"http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ))
    {
        echo "<li  class = \"navigation\" id = \"".$item['identificator']."\"                                                                tltle=\"".$item['title']."\"><a href=\"".$item['link']."\" class=\"active\">".$item['name']."</a></li>";
        }else{
            echo "<li  class = \"navigation\" id = \"".$item['identificator']."\" tltle=\"".$item['title']."\"><a href=\"".$item['link']."\">".$item['name']."</a></li>";}
   ;}

   ?>           
 </ul>
```

Comment: what data does the ajax function get?

Comment: just a [div #central]. There is html only.

Comment: i mean what does the `url: $(this).children('a').prop("href")` return?

Comment: Now it works fine with your help of course. But I have 1 moment which I try to do myself first. Many thanks(I can't vote couse my rep < 15!)Can I ask you to have a look through my jQ script. Im not sure that history works fine. My purpose as usual is history, browser buttons "forward" "back" and direct link. really gratefull for your time and attention

Comment: i could help you but i dont see all your code (i dont see your javascript to go back), i would suggest to think about easy usable functions (interface) like: `goBackInHistory()`,  `addToHistory(title,url)` etc. This wil make your code easier to read, understand and debuggable ;).

Comment: Do you mean I need to place some buttons for goBack and goForward? It is my navigation and just I need that is browser back-forward buttons should work fine and all the history should be saved. that is it!

Answer (score 0):

you success function does not look fine:

```
success: function(data){
   jqObj = $(data);
   var addSmth = jqObj.find('#central');
   $("#central").html('').html(addSmth);
```

i think you mean something of the following?

```
success: function(data){ //data is normally just a string
    $("#title").html(data));
```

or

```
function(data){ //if the data you return is a css notation (eg: #id) of the location of the title name
  JqObj = $(data);
  var addSmth = jqObj.find('#central').html();
  $("#central").html(addSmth);
```

@slowing down:

`$('li[id^=id_]')` might slow things down. I suggest you uses classes for this.

also you could create the `nivoSlider` after creating your on click events. if you want to be sure the on click events are all done asap.

Comment: I remade code like you suggest me, but it still blinks with the fast clicking(once in a second, no so actually fast)